# Remove xticks with decimals in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I want to remove xticks with decimals. I just want to leave the years 1992 to 1995.

[image: remove ticks]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
df

#yerr = margin of error or confidence of interval = std/sqrt(pop. size) * z-score, a 95% confidence interval is approximately 1.96
#for under 30, use t-score, otherwise z-score
average = df.mean(axis = 1)
std = df.std(axis = 1)
average, std
#

mgn_error = (std/np.sqrt(df.shape[1])) * 1.96
mgn_error

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
xvals = range(df.shape[0])
bars = plt.bar(df.index, average, yerr = mgn_error, color = 'lightslategrey', error_kw=dict(lw=2, capsize=20, capthick=2))
plt.show()
```

I tried using:

```
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index, alpha = 0.8)
```

But this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Your first code works fine for me producing only integer year values. I am using `'2.2.3'` matplotlib version

Comment: Jeez, I am using Coursera's Notebook.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what's new in that Notebook. Try it on your local installation

Comment: Simply use `plt.xticks(df.index)` or, if that still shows decimals, `plt.xticks(df.index, df.index)`

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.